# WP Image upload not working with error and add new plugin search loads endless, how to fix?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using my Wordpress site when I found out that my upload images in wordpress is not working, example, in post pages when I try to upload the image (display photo) current uploaded images are not showing and when I upload an image it says

> " An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later. "

I tried to enable/disable plugins to see if there are plugin issues but seems like its not about the plugin.

also the add new plugin looks like having an error, when I search for a certain plugin it loads continuously without any result but when I refresh the page the result shows.

how to fix?

**UPDATE**
I found out that it is actually uploading, but it still says

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

[here is the image sample of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVL4.png)

and in the async_upload it is successful with : {"success":true,"data":{"id":223298,"title":title"}

***what do you think is the problem here?***

Comment: is it on live server or in localhost?

Comment: This might be useful. https://sebastian.expert/fix-wordpress-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again-later/

Comment: Vishwa it is in staging live server

Comment: Please check which type of file and which size of file are you uploading. Make debuge true and then try to upload. Also check in console for error and add error here.

Comment: please check my update

Comment: try your server's write permissions in uploads directory, and also try uploading smaller file (<1mb)

Comment: @Vishwa based on my update, It is uploading, but the error is still showing and can't pick the image uploaded for posting. what will be the problem here?

Comment: can you see the image uploaded into uploads folder correctly, using ftp?

Comment: @Vishwa yes it is uploading

Comment: check these please [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726630), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767629/) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037751/) , [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541834/wordpress-file-upload-issue-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again)